# is there a simple way to add Alt Text to the submenu arrows in GWT?

Tags: gwt, accessibility

A client of mine is particularly keen on the Wave toolbar as a measure of accessibility, and will not accept any red errors for any reason.

The sub-menu arrow in GWT by default has no alt-text associated with it, causing a wave toolbar error when the menu is on screen.

Is there a simple way to add alt text to this image, or am I going to have to sub-class MenuBar?

thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: I haven't used GWT personally, so I cannot comment too much. I would say you should file a bug to have it fixed at the api/core level.